# Variance of Portfolio Return

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am struggling to understand the following proof. I do not understand the highlighted red step. Please could this be broken down so that I can understand it. It seems like a manipulation of summations, and I can't seem to find an explanation.

[image: variance of portfolio return question]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_it_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i\overline{r_i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i(t_i-\overline{r_i}).$$
(This is just distributivity.)

After this, the step you marked is simply replacing $A^2$ by $A\cdot A$, where $A=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i(t_i-\overline{r_i})$. Indeed
$$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i(t_i-\overline{r_i})\right)^2 = \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i(t_i-\overline{r_i})\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i(t_i-\overline{r_i})\right) = \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i(t_i-\overline{r_i})\right)\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n w_j(t_j-\overline{r_j})\right).$$

(In the very last step, the name of the variable was changed from $i$ to $j$.)

Comment: Thanks, got it! Can't seem to think remembering, about wikipedia having this property listed...

Answer (score 1):

Simply follows from the fact that
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ia_j
$$